# how to run external application from windows services in python?

Tags: python, windows, service, windows-services

I have simple windows service in python and I need to run some external application. I tried to use `os.system` and `subprocess.call`, however it does not work in window service.

My simple service:

```
class AppServerSvc(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "MyService1"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Test Service1"
    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):

        ########## That is my trial #################
        os.system("C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe")
        #############################################

        rc = None
        while rc != win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, 3000)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Please be specific.

Comment: The notepad.exe does not launch. And the reason is, that I lauch it in windows service.